# Use of COMMON without declaring variables in FORTRAN

Tags: fortran

I am going through and analyzing a legacy **FORTRAN** code and i found in some of the places where **COMMON** is used and the list of variables used do not have any data type

```
DIMENSION X(50),Y(50),VER(20),FCUR(20),H3(6),H4(6),G(6),TTAT(20),   
 XX(50),YY(50),EFFS(5),EFFI(5),PARA(6,9),ZZ(50)                      
  COMMON X,Y,PARA,TTAT,TTAT1,TTAT2,TTAT4,XQ,XL,WZ,     SA1,K7,        
 FVOL1,K1,K2,M5,RFIL,TNO,SAF,CFT,CFY,DSH                             
  COMMON     ACUL,AFMAX,AL,ALA,ALF,ALP,AKC,AKP,AMC,AS,AMP,AKE1,ATG,   
 AN1,AMPF,ALG,AKE,BC,BG,BA,BT,BAT,BTMAX,CUST1,CUST2,CUST3,CUST4,     
 CAP,CYCLE,CYCLL,CYCLH,CW,CH,   CAT,CAR,CMT,CMR,CAPL,CAPH,DATE1,     
 DATE2,DATE3,D1,DA,DB,DAMP,DY1,DBAR,D2L1,D2L2,DC,D4,DEND,ER,EX,
```

I have seen that this variables `X,Y,PARA,TTAT,TTAT1,TTAT2,TTAT4,XQ` etc. are used in calculation but no data type is declared for them .

I assume the following rule is implemented here 
Fortran variables with names starting `[I J K L M N]` were INTEGER and everything else was REAL.

SO is the same rule followed for common also ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Exactly.

You should probably start with IMPLICIT NONE in each routine and explicitly define the variables.
INTENT also makes for ease of reading the goes-into and comes-outta ...

e.g.:

```
 SUBROUTINE A(B, C, I, IO)
 USE My_Module_from_a_common
 IMPLICIT NONE
 DOUBLE, DIMENSION(:), INTENT(IN   ) :: B
 REAL,             , INTENT(INOUT) :: C
 INTEGER,          , INTENT(  OUT) :: I
 LOGICAL,          , INTENT(IN   ) :: IO
```

In modern code, a module is compiled.
Then the USE statement is like an import for the module.

A USE -module- is effectively the merge of the /common/ block and INCLUDE '-file-'...  with some additional benefits.
All the items defined as PUBLIC are global, and private are internal.

e.g.:

```
MODULE My_Module_From_a_Common
PUBLIC
REAL, DIMENSION(50), CONTIGUOUS :: X, Y, YY, ZZ
REAL, DIMENSION(6 ), CONTIGUOUS :: H3, H4
!etc     X(50),Y(50),VER(20),FCUR(20),H3(6),H4(6),G(6),TTAT(20),   
!etc    XX(50),YY(50),EFFS(5),EFFI(5),PARA(6,9),ZZ(50)                      
!etc  COMMON X,Y,PARA,TTAT,TTAT1,TTAT2,TTAT4,XQ,XL,WZ,     SA1,K7,        
!etc FVOL1,K1,K2,M5,RFIL,TNO,SAF,CFT,CFY,DSH                            
!etc  COMMON     ACUL,AFMAX,AL,ALA,ALF,ALP,AKC,AKP,AMC,AS,AMP,AKE1,ATG,   
!etc AN1,AMPF,ALG,AKE,BC,BG,BA,BT,BAT,BTMAX,CUST1,CUST2,CUST3,CUST4,     
!etc CAP,CYCLE,CYCLL,CYCLH,CW,CH,   CAT,CAR,CMT,CMR,CAPL,CAPH,DATE1,     
!etc DATE2,DATE3,D1,DA,DB,DAMP,DY1,DBAR,D2L1,D2L2,DC,D4,DEND,ER,EX,
END MODULE My_Module_From_a_Common
```

The advantage is that the use makes all the common instantiations the same if you need to add, change, or remove a variable.

When you compile -check all and -warn all, or -check uninit and -warn unused can be helpful to work out stuff...

In a routine or function save is implied by = something... e.g. these are the same, otherwise there is no saving of the result the next time in.

```
REAL       :: A = 22.1
REAL, SAVE :: A
```

Comment: Please, I asked you alredy. Really do not introduce `kind=4` to tech people good practices. It is BAD practise. REALLY BAD actyally. Please don't do it. I will probably downvoting that in the future. Please...

Comment: A much less important remark: the contiguous is superficial in this case, it has no effect, even if allowed (not sure). It is for pointers and assumed shape dummy arguments.

Comment: Thank Vladimir - Why is KIND= bad? Or do you suggest REAL and DOUBLE? or using the r_c_interoperability stuff like C_INT, C_LONG?

Comment: Because the value 4 is not portable. It is not the same as real*4. Some compilers use kind=1 to mean the same as kind=4 in other compilers. You should use a named constant. It is up to you which value you assign to it or if you use from a module. I use often real32 and 64 from iso_fortran_env but somoteimes those from iso_c_binding are more appropriate. And sometimes I use kind(1.) and kind(1.d0) to initialize my own named constant if the meaning is clearly Fortran single and Fortran double precision.

Comment: Minor issue: the line `DOUBLE, DIMENSION(:), INTENT(IN   ) :: B` shouldn't compile.  Methinks a missing `PRECISION` perhaps.

Comment: Yeah High Mark...  I use REAL(KIND=8) on fort, but slowly changing things to C_FLOAT... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the implicit rules are in effect. If a common block is defined in an include find, it is really better to define the types of all variables because you can include it in procedures with different implicit rules then (including `implicit none`). Common blocks included from an include file follow the rules of the subroutine which includes it.